# How to pass string to Controller using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I cannot seem to do this very simple task of passing a string to a controller when a button is pressed. The data received, is always null. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Form:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProcessName" class="control-control">Process Name</label>
        <input id="ProcessName" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose process name">
        <small id="subtitle" class="form-text text-muted">Text under input field.</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addElement">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#addElement").click(function () {
        var processName = $("#ProcessName").val();

        // I've tried this method
        $.post('@Url.Action("AddProcessName")', processName, function (data, status) {
                    alert(data)
        });

       // And also this one, but both of them don't work.
       // I did not try them at the same time, of course
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddProcessName")',
            data: processName,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response)
                };
        });
    });
});
```

Server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddProcessName(string data)
{
    pm.ID = 1;
    pm.Name = data; // I put a breakpoint here to check the value of 'data'
    return Content(pm.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're telling your Action to expect a variable named `data`, yet you're not sending that. You need to change the `data` property of your jQuery AJAX request to this:

```
data: { data: processName },
```

I'd also suggest you return JSON from the Action as plain text can be flaky at best due to the way whitespace may or may not be interpreted. Try this:

```js
$("#addElement").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("AddProcessName")',
    data: { 
      data: $("#ProcessName").val() 
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      // use console.log for debugging, and access the property of the deserialised object
      console.log(response.Name); 
    };
  });
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddProcessName(string data)
{
    pm.ID = 1;
    pm.Name = data;
    return Json(new { Name = pm.Name });
    // or just:
    // return Json(pm);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Thanks for the tip to use JSON instead.